# Strange PHP behavior: empty, !, and count

Tags: php

Someone can explain to me if this "freak" behavior its what i should expect.

I'm debbuging some code and got this:

I geting some result on $data and create this if to be sure it's $data have some info.

So:

```
if(!$data || empty($data) || count($data) == 0)
```

And aways geting in the if.

So i do some var_dump to see and wow.

```
var_dump(!$data , empty($data) , count($data));
```

go this:

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
int(1)
```

how count data = 1 and !$data = true and empty($data) = true?

I hope isn't stupid question, i'm sorry if is.

Comment: why not `var_dump($data)` so we can see what's there? :)

Comment: Never use `count` to validate strings ....

Comment: My data its a return from fetchAll on $res, like this return current($res->toArray());

Comment: I can't var_dump on $data now, but i'll try and feed here to we know more. Thanks all and i'll mark the right answer after i know what's comming on data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Count** Returns the number of elements in var. If var is not an array or an object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There is one exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Look at PHP Documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Answer (score 8):

From the [PHP Documentation on `count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

> Returns the number of elements in var. If var is not an array or an
>   object with implemented Countable interface, 1 will be returned. There
>   is one exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Most likely, `$data` is not an array. Double check with a var_dump on it

```
var_dump($data)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
!0 = true;
empty(0) = true;
count(0) = 1
```

Your value is 0 or an empty string.

Comment: Or an empty string. Or the value `0`.

Comment: your right, count(null) is actually 0 so it has to be one of the two you mentioned